# Unable to install correct driver for Android device not getting detected in DDMS?

Tags: android

I am not able to install USB-driver from "sdk/extras/google/usb_driver" and also am unable to do so using an external driver for my Sony mt27i device.

Where can I get the correct drivers for my Sony mt27i device?

Comment: Can u tell what exact error you are getting while installing the sdk/extras/google/usb_driver?

Comment: did U enabled the USB debugging mode in Developer options?

Answer (score 2):

Hello user3059993,
                  try to fellow some sequence of steps.

- 1)Go to device manager
- 2)than Usb Device
- 3)Right click on your connected device and click on update driver
- 4)there will secondary option to browse the drive here give the path
  of google usb driver

  or

fellow this link-
http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

i think it will work after that,thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to install [SnapPea](http://web.snappea.com/) in your PC which detects most number of Android devices. I was having a Tablet from China whose drivers where not there, so even that was detected by SnapPea. It will automatically ask you to download SnapPea for mobile also. Its great to have only one installation for all drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look on this docs
http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Answer (score 1):

try the below steps

1.on the device reset debugger options.. this might work

or

1.go to "device manager settings"

2.select your device and "update driver"

4 select "browse my computer for device software"

5.select "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer"

6.Select " Your mobile device MTP " from the popup or the driver related to your device.

This will setup your device again.. and will be ready to use

Using Ubuntu

you can try the following commands

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
adb devices
```

These commands also work on windows command prompt

Answer (score 0):

Install drivers from: http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/

To detect the device by adb, you need to set the device USB mode to **Mass Storage Mode** (MSC). See settings - xperia connectivity - usb connectivity